# how to make a row maintain its position of entry even though its primary key id number is less than the earlier row entered

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

> Please guys, my primary key id is auto generated from my java code. Because of that, some of the id numbers of the new row to be inserted is less than the older rows already inserted in the database . My question is: Is it possible to make the database maintain  each rows in the order by which they where inserted even though the new rows have lesser id numbers as compared to the older ones? . i use Mysql in phpmyadmin. Thanks

Comment: Things would have been a lot more easier had you left the task of auto-incementing the field to the DB, instead of delegating it to the application layer.

Comment: Let the database do what it does best. It's not messing with your code, so why are you messing with its primary key generation.

Comment: I agree with two previous comments. I would add that the order in the table doesn't mean anything. If you want to get your results ordered, use an `ORDER BY`, don't trust the row order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any way to create non-clustered primary keys in mySql.

But in MS Sql Server there is way to create non-clustered primary key as below

> ALTER TABLE my_table DROP CONSTRAINT pk_my_table;
>
> ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT pk_my_table PRIMARY KEY
>   NONCLUSTERED (id);

or

If you are not concerned with actually keeping your java generated id as primary key.

And you want to maintain natural ordering of rows, create a separate column (with auto-generated sequence) and make it primary key.

Comment: If your problem is solve, please accept the answer :-)